# How can I disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I'm interested in how to disable the new HUD.

Any ideas?