# How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-2d, hud

A number of games, Emacs, and the terminal make extensive use of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Can Unity be configured to respect this key, rather than launching the HUD with it?

Comment: the HUD is really annoying

Comment: I agree. Having the Alt key launch the HUD pretty much guarantees that you're going to interfere the the proper functioning of most non-trivial apps.

Comment: It makes it extremely difficult to follow the Unity3d game engine tutorials. Alt is constantly used when creating the game world, for example rotating the scene viewport, which happens dozens of times a minute if you are creating a complicated object.

Comment: Any modifier key that is being used by it own is a terrible idea. Same thing with `Start` key.

Comment: It's really a stupid design.  annoying.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

Open the System Settings application either by going to `Session Indicator` in Unity panel, or by searching for `System Settings` using the HUD.

[image]

Then go to `Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers`.  You can redefine the HUD key with the *Key to show the HUD* option. Pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will disable the HUD shortcut altogether.

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard settings window, in the Launchers section]

If you set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd> manually, the setting distinguishes between the left and right Alt key.  So if you want to maintain general behaviour and still use Alt combinations, this may be an alternate solution for you.

Comment: Setting it to Super (the windows key) makes it the same as Win7 and OSX and doesn't have the issue that Alt has which is used in quite a few programs.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The left alt key still triggers HUD. I wonder if some update occurred which nullified this fix. I'm really surprised that this is even an issue: Emacs anyone? Geez.

Comment: I set it to `Alt+Windows` as it kept popping up when I was switching tabs in Firefox. This combo works very well and doesn't interfere with normal Dash operations.

Comment: Yes! Finally got rid of it!

After all this time I still don't know the purpose of this HUD "Execute command"... Can anyone explain?

Comment: @Lucas Pottersky with HUD you can access all apps menu commands and indicators commands

Comment: Wow. I am kicking myself for not searching for this sooner! (Also, in retrospect, it's so obvious... I really shouldn't have had to *search* for it at all.)

Comment: It should have been just alt-super by default, especially with all the games coming up for Linux. Thanks.

Comment: This setting seems to reset itself every few weeks. I set it to Disabled, and sure enough a little while later it's bound to L Alt again. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: By default it was set to `Alt L`, and I failed to change it to right `Alt`. Aside from this, it works :)

Comment: @Dogweather: It showed "disabled" for me too, and re-disabling it worked... I tried setting it back to Alt, without success, which isn't a problem, I don't want the menu coming up at all.

Comment: Can these settings be controlled programmatically?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. For some reason, when I try to set it to Left Alt, or Right Alt, it sets the binding to Disabled. Is there a config text file somewhere which allows you to set this option?

Comment: @becko Same for me, but using jokerdino's compizconfig-settings-manager method below worked (and could set it to Alt+Windows).

Comment: it works in ubuntu 14.10

Comment: @Dogweather Did you set it though? I set mine to Alt+L and it stopped popping up the HUD when I did Alt+D in the browser. Click that line and set it even if it already says the keystroke you want to use. I guess I was accidentally pressing Alt+Super+D when I tried to do Alt+D, but Alt+L worked for me (Alt+Super was the default).

Comment: Would love to find the corresponding setting in Ubuntu-MATE. (alt get captured away, thus alt-<mousedrag> [does not work in virtual box as desired](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3361#comment:5))

Comment: These items don't show up on my recent Ubuntu. Does anybody know how to disable showing the hud via Alt on Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: How to do it in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 63):

You can use [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] to change the key used to show the HUD.

To install it, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

After installing it, open it (`ccsm`) and go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

[image]

Click on the button for the option *Key to show the HUD* and a dialog similar to the one shown below will appear.

[image]

Click on *Grab key combination* and press your desired new key combination and press enter. After that, click on *OK* button and the new key combination will trigger the HUD from now on.

Comment: This won't work on Unity-2D...

Comment: @nastys it at least work in Unity 3D very good

Comment: Keybindings from CCSM may still be respected when running Unity2D.

Comment: Really. When unity is activated some of key settings in standard shortcuts are ignore. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem in Evolution caused when inserting the mail recipients and a comma and space are inserted after pressing AltGr key to obtain the @. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can this app be controlled programmatically?  If not, how can I programmatically do the same thing that this app is doing?

Comment: @gonzobrains Pretty much every little thing that CCSM is doing is accessible through Gsettings API. Which settings do you plan to tweak?

Comment: I want to disable key-combinations, print screen, etc.

Comment: While this is a solution that works, but just for disabling alt key for HUD display doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: Thanks, this saves my day. I am with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it solves the problem of content assist popup in Eclipse disappearing when pressing `alt`.

Comment: No "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" shows up to me. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Unity isn't enabled on my recent Ubuntu. Does anybody know how to disable showing the hud via Alt on Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 20):

#### You can configure HUD with help of **`gsettings:`**

```
DESCRIPTION
       gsettings offers a simple commandline interface to GSettings.It lets you get, set or monitor an individual key for changes.
```

- **To get current key run following command in terminal:**

  ```
  $ gsettings get org.compiz.integrated show-hud
  ['<Alt>']
  ```
- **To change key (let <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>) run following command in terminal:**

  ```
  gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud "['<Alt><Super>']"
  ```

Now when you press only <kbd>Alt</kbd> then HUD not shown. But it is configured to shown by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>!

You can set valid Key-Combination instead of `"['<Alt><Super>']"`.

Comment: I restored using `gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud "['<Alt><Super>']"` thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between using this and dconf write/read?

Comment: @gonzobrains Visit https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/dconf which states `dconf is a low-level configuration system. Its main purpose is to provide a backend to GSettings on platforms that don't already have configuration storage systems.`

Comment: @gonzobrains At [API](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/dconf#dconf_API) Also **`Note: Most applications will not want to interface directly with dconf, but rather with GSettings.`**

Comment: I have been able to use gsettings to disable key combinations under Ubuntu 14.04 but this doesn't seem to work with 12.04.

Comment: @gonzobrains 12.04 uses `gconf`, not `dconf`/`gsettings`

Comment: @gonzobrains, https://askubuntu.com/q/249887/372612

Comment: This has no effect on my recent Ubuntu. Does anybody know how to disable showing the hud via Alt on Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 16):

## On "Ubuntu 13.04 (raring)" you can execute:

**disable HUD:**

```
dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '[""]'
```

**enable/reset HUD ('Alt L'):**

```
dconf write /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud '["&lt;Alt&gt;"]'
```

Comment: works even if the setting in not listet in the system settings testet with 14.04 (development branch)

Comment: it works at 14.04

Comment: Do dconf changes require a reboot?  I'm trying to modifying the screenshot command and it doesn't seem to take effect right away.

Comment: I think the &lt; and &gt; should be < and > when actually typing it in the command line; at least for me, when I used the encodings it didn't work, but when I used ["<Alt>"] it did work.

Comment: Hint: It should be running by your user, not by `root` via `sudo`

Answer (score 15):

Well it's Called [HUD](https://askubuntu.com/a/115991/37006). The new feature of Unity.

To prevent it from appearing, you can disable its key binding in keyboard shortcuts.

Open system settings by going to `Session Indicator` in Unity panel.

[image]

In system settings select `Keyboard`. Under `Shortcuts` tab, Click on `Key to show the HUD. and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to disable it. That's it!

[image]

Comment: Clearing the key doesn't disable the HUD option

Comment: Thank you! I initially didn't realize BACKSPACE is how to disable the shortcut.

Answer (score 10):

In Ubuntu 12.04 I changed shortcut for summoning HUD in `System Settings... > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Key to show the HUD`.

Now my left Alt is happy again :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the system settings, just change the keyboard shortcut for "Key to show the HUD" (under 'Launchers'). As a suggestion, set it to activate when both the alt keys are pressed at the same time, instead of just one. It makes using VMs much less annoying.

Answer (score -3):

Ubuntu 14.04.1: Opening an Emacs Session in which Typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't Open the HUD.

1. In the Desktop environment, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter a terminal screen.
2. Enter your username and password as prompted.
3. At the command prompt, open an Emacs session by typing `emacs`.
4. Now, using <kbd>Alt</kbd> as <kbd>Meta</kbd> won't open the HUD.
5. Return to the Desktop at any time by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

<sub>Source: [An Introduction to the Command Line_ (p.12) on the FLOSS Manuals page.](http://en.flossmanuals.net/)</sub>

Comment: Telling the user to bail out to one of the `tty`s isn't a helpful option for most users and, on some computers, isn't usable. I have a laptop with a 4K display that produce text that is pretty much illegible at a reasonable distance.