# Running WoW on ubuntu, is it possible to fix the weird "Alt" button behavior?

Tags: 12.04, wine, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I've managed to get WoW working smoothly through wine (quite impressed), but the Alt key seems to be behaving weirdly. I've disabled the "drag window" feature so it wouldn't interfere anymore, but it still has some weird behavior.

When playing, to walk I hold W and control direction with the mouse while keeping my finger on right click. If I press the Alt key while doing this (W+RightClick), my camera direction is being released and I'm controlling the cursor instead of the character direction.

Any idea if there's a fix for this kind of thing ? I'm thinking it's because Ubuntu still have some kind of control over the window, can I make wine capture the keyboard/mouse completely ?

Comment: Fixed this myself, it was a keybind from unity grabbing focus (Alt).

Compiz Config > Unity > Key to show the HUD, remove or change to something else.