# How to stop HUD from appearing while video playback?

Tags: unity, hud

When I watch a movie in VLC, I want to jump forward or backward in the movie using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>, but when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> the HUD appears.

Is it necessary to change some key bindings (like shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)) or is there a better solution? Maybe I can disable HUD while having focus on VLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HUD only appears if you press and release <kbd>Alt</kbd> key instantly, If you hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for little bit longer it won't appear.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. But sometimes I forget to hold the Alt key for a little bit longer ...

Comment: @Christian Another option is to change the hot keys in VLC preferences.