# How can I disable [alt] for search?

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

In 12.04, the [Alt] key pops up the HUD. That's not a problem, but, when using [Alt]+... it pops up as well.

For instance on pushing [Alt]+[Left Arrow] which I use continually when navigating with Firefox (that's the 'back' functionality).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/337210/136964).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*You can easily change the hotkey for the HUD by going to **System Settings --> Keyboard --> Short-cuts** as in the following picture :*

[image]

**Note that:** Clicking ALT fast , shows the HUD. But When you click and hold you can use it easily for another function. I use ALT without any problems.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't install ccsm. But I disabled the [Alt l] key from the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @GUIJunkie: I've changed the answer. I've forgotten about Keyboard Shortcuts method. BTW this way is better than using ccsm because it is dangerous.

Comment: Press BACKSPACE to remove the shortcut.

Comment: In Eclipse I set `alt + down` to be "move one line down", it's working when I edit text normally, but when there's a popup of content assist it fails, because by pressing `alt` the focus changes to menubar and the popup of content assist disappears. Any idea?