# How do I prevent Ubuntu from capturing the Alt key to show the HUD?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, unity-dash, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

When I press ALT key on virtualbox machine (ex XP), ubuntu 12.04 catch that key.

How to prevent ubuntu catch ALT key?

Thank you~

Comment: I _think_ your only choices are for the guest to capture all special keys, or no special keys.  Do you want the key passed on to the host machine, or do you simply want Ubuntu to ignore it?

Comment: I want ubuntu to Ignore.

Comment: I would see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133776/how-can-i-disable-alt-for-search/133777#133777

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Disabling the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key from showing the HUD:

- Install CCSM with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

  [image]
- Start it from the Dash or by typing `ccsm` from the terminal.
- Type "Unity" in the filter box on the left, and click on the Ubuntu Unity Plugin:

  [image]
- Click on the `<Alt>` button the red arrow points to, and then uncheck the *Enabled* box. Click OK and close CCSM -- the Alt shortcut is now disabled.
- If you no longer need CCSM, please consider uninstalling it.

  [image]

Comment: Why are your recommending uninstalling CCSM?

Comment: Because it seems newbies often want to play with it once they try it out, and the next thing you know, it crashes, all they have is a blank desktop and they panic :)

Comment: Ha. Gotcha. But that's how they learn, right? /grin

Comment: haha, that's exactly what I did. But I agree with Tom, in fixing it I learnt something.

Comment: Is there a way to make Hud only capture the *right* Alt key, not the left Alt?

Comment: To capture only the right Alt key, click "Grab key combination", press the right Alt key (it should show "Multi_key"), then close the "Please press the new key" dialog box.

Comment: These comments do not inspire confidence in the accepted answer. I found this article, it worked, and doesn't require installing a high-risk unstable tool: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key