# how to disable alt+w unity binding

Tags: unity

I can't for the life of me find where it's specified. Oddly I don’t think I’ve had this problem before in unity. When editing in emacs, the alt+w short-cut is vital and every time I press it I get the "type your command prompt" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the <kbd>alt</kbd> key. Any combination using it will trigger the HUD. You can use the package compizconfig-settings-manager.

Step 1 : Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Step 2 : After installing it, open it and go to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". Click on the button for the option Key to show the HUD.

Step 3 : Click on Grab key combination and press any new key combination and press enter. After that, alt should no longer trigger the HUD.

Also, I believe this has been already explained more clearly :

[How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

Comment: Or you can go to *System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts* as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/133777/325849).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is not a shortcut in unity. To get the "Type your command here prompt". You press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button. I think there is a gap in your typing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> keys. Try pressing them together faster

Comment: My case is the opposite. I need to type Alt+W very slowly (i.e. press alt, then keep the key pressed for a while, then press W) in order not to trigger unity. I will change the HUD key then. Perhaps Ubuntu does not expect any of its users use emacs...