# Disable 'type your command` prompt on pressing alt

Tags: unity, interface, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and noticed the little prompt that appears on top of every window when you press the Alt key:

[image]

Does anyone know how to disable/remove it? It's really intrusive in my opinion and I would like to get rid of it.