# Alt key in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hud, ibus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

The new HUD in 12.04 uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, which conflicts with the way utilities like IBUS switch input methods. Is there a workaround?

Comment: This might be a bug.  If you don't get a response in a few days, you may want to consider filing a bug against unity

Answer (score 2):

You can go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts, and change the key to show the HUD.

*note: the ALT key is named "ALT L" and is bound to (System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts) -> Launchers -> Key to show the HUD