# How to avoid evolution adds a "," when pressing alt?

Tags: evolution

I have an annoying problem. Every time i want to enter a mail adress in evolution, it adds a "," when pressing alt (needed to type "@").

So, when i want to send a mail to info@ubuntu.com, it gives me: info, @ubuntu.com which of course does not work. I can adjust it manually though but it keeps being annoying

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/943104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/943104). It could be, or not, HUD related (*). You can try to disable or change the shortcut key to open the HUD to something different from ALT, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key). If it works please report back here and in the bug report, if it doesn't feel free to downvote this answer.

One possible (but highly speculative) explanation is that evolution is programmed so that it adds a comma to the field when it lost focus (to ease adding more addresses). When you hit ALT, the HUD gets focus and Evolution inserts a comma.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. I did exactly as explained in the link and now it does work normal. Thanks!