# How do I uninstall the HUD altogether?

Tags: hud

I don't want to just disable the key binding to invoke the HUD, I want to remove the HUD.

I notice in System Monitor that something called hud-service is taking up 65 megabytes. Besides that, I'm always invoking the HUD by accident merely by going back a page in a web browser. So I'd like to just completely uninstall anything pertaining to the HUD.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think is possible, since the HUD is part of Unity itself, you can check:

- [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

There they show you how to disable it

Comment: That is what I was reading before I asked my question. It sounds like basically all I would disable would be a key binding, but a daemon could still be occupying resources.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check this post which seems like a duplicate
[How can I disable hud-service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210387/how-can-i-disable-hud-service)