# How can I disable hud-service?

Tags: cpu-load, hud

hud-service keeps eating my cpu. This is troublematic, specially because I'm running 12.04 in a Asus EEEPC. There are a lot of answers on how to change hud bindings, but what I reallyw wonder if there is a way to disable or uninstall hud-service.

Thanks in advance,
Marcos

Comment: You're not new to askubuntu, so is it safe to assume you're not interested in xubuntu or lubuntu (a lighter desktop environment)?

Comment: @Rucent88 nope :3

Comment: You answered "nope" to not being interested in lighter desktops, which would mean "yes, I am interested in a lighter desktop". But I'm inclined to think that wasn't what you meant to answer...

Comment: my bad, I actually mean I'm not interested :)

Comment: The hud is actually a really neat feature - searching all the menus, it's like a shortcut finder.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open a terminal and do

on 32bit system

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/indicator-appmenu/hud-service
```

on 64bit system

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
```

which [removes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes) **`-`** the [execute](http://www.examplenow.com/chmod/) mode **`x`** (i.e., [permission](http://oreilly.com/linux/command-directory/cmd.csp?path=c/chmod)) from **`hud-service`**.

Done.

You *may* want to gently `end` (or violently `kill`) the currently running `hud-service` (or reboot, etc) for "changes to take effect" immediately...

Comment: I'll try that today!

Comment: I tried already :-) and no hud-service exists in resources (system monitor).

Comment: on 64-bit linux (13.04) it's in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service

Comment: How to revert these changes?

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam `sudo chmod +x` instead of `-x`

Comment: killall doesn't work and kill ends the session. `chmod -x` would disable it for all time not just the one time it malfunctions.

Comment: It's better to remove its package, to prevent it from returning due to upgrading system: `sudo apt-get remove hud`

Comment: @MortezaE the OP asks how to disable the HUD service, not removing it. Remove a package is always the easiest solution. He may want to enable/disable the service at will.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read this answer here on a similar thread:

https://askubuntu.com/a/693203/223872

> The HUD is related to the Unity Launcher. For example it analyzes the
>   files you are using and offers them when you press Super.
>
> On my system (Ubuntu 15.10) the hud-service started using 100% of one
>   CPU.
>
> I solved this by installing Compiz Config Settings Manager (ccsm) and
>   disabled all effects and set "Enable Low Graphics Mode" in "Ubuntu
>   Unity Plugin":

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
ccsm
```

Although you can indeed disable the executable bit, when the system upgrades, it may reset that bit to on when the file is overridden on new updates.

Also, the comment above the one I posted above mentions that the hud-service is in the package `hud`, which if you just don't want, it might be better to just remove the package entirely.

https://askubuntu.com/a/699888/223872

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the `ubuntu unity plugin` to diable the `alt` key trigger for that service. It might just be what you want to do.