# Why Ubuntu hud-service consuming too much RAM memory?

Tags: 16.04, ram

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and It's a core i3 notebook with 8GB RAM.
It's hanging if I open 2/3 program at a time. When I've seen system monitor I'm shocked!! hud-service taking about 5.5 GB memory!! How is this possible??!! :O

Comment: Ifyou don't use HUD, you can remove it (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/526264/what-is-the-hud-service-responsible-for)

Comment: look at this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/526264/what-is-the-hud-service-responsible-for
i did:
sudo apt-get purge hud