# Ubuntu 14.10 crashing regularly

Tags: 14.10, crash

Here is the copy of apport.log. Can someone help me understand and help me troubleshoot ? This is crashing almost everyday.

```
 /var/log$ more apport.log

ERROR: apport (pid 3635) Fri Aug 26 11:22:49 2016: called for pid 2267, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 3635) Fri Aug 26 11:22:49 2016: executable: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service (command line "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service")
ERROR: apport (pid 3635) Fri Aug 26 11:22:49 2016: gdbus call error: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: apport (pid 3635) Fri Aug 26 11:22:49 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 3635) Fri Aug 26 11:22:49 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 3745) Fri Aug 26 16:57:11 2016: called for pid 2260, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 3745) Fri Aug 26 16:57:11 2016: executable: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service (command line "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service")
ERROR: apport (pid 3745) Fri Aug 26 16:57:11 2016: gdbus call error: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: apport (pid 3745) Fri Aug 26 16:57:11 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 3745) Fri Aug 26 16:57:11 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 7656) Fri Aug 26 22:04:27 2016: called for pid 2025, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 7656) Fri Aug 26 22:04:27 2016: executable: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service (command line "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service")
ERROR: apport (pid 7656) Fri Aug 26 22:04:27 2016: gdbus call error: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: apport (pid 7656) Fri Aug 26 22:04:27 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 7656) Fri Aug 26 22:04:29 2016: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_lib_i386-linux-gnu_hud_hud-service.1000.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 3673) Fri Aug 26 23:23:56 2016: called for pid 2046, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 3673) Fri Aug 26 23:23:56 2016: executable: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service (command line "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service")
ERROR: apport (pid 3673) Fri Aug 26 23:23:56 2016: gdbus call error: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: apport (pid 3673) Fri Aug 26 23:23:56 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 3673) Fri Aug 26 23:23:56 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
ERROR: apport (pid 2983) Sat Aug 27 13:37:58 2016: called for pid 2331, signal 5, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 2983) Sat Aug 27 13:37:58 2016: executable: /usr/bin/compiz (command line "compiz")
ERROR: apport (pid 2983) Sat Aug 27 13:37:59 2016: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 2983) Sat Aug 27 13:38:24 2016: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash
ERROR: apport (pid 3214) Sat Aug 27 13:39:01 2016: called for pid 2317, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 3214) Sat Aug 27 13:39:01 2016: executable: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service (command line "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service")
ERROR: apport (pid 3214) Sat Aug 27 13:39:01 2016: gdbus call error: Error connecting: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: apport (pid 3214) Sat Aug 27 13:39:01 2016: debug: session gdbus call: 
ERROR: apport (pid 3214) Sat Aug 27 13:39:01 2016: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

After following a suggestion in the comment to remove compiz I lost my launcher. Now the question is kept on hold asking to upgrade ubuntu. Now my question is does upgrading my Ubuntu to 15.04 and then to 15.10 and there to 16.04 LTS help me in getting back my launcher ?

Also please help me on upgrade path as I would like to update using DVD because online update if in case of internet and power outage could cause permanent loss of data. Please suggest on upgrade path and method.

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this? What did you do prior to the problem occuring? Do you experience the crashes running any other operating system, can you reproduce it running the live image?

Comment: Possibly slightly-related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/526264/what-is-the-hud-service-responsible-for and http://askubuntu.com/questions/210387/how-can-i-disable-hud-service

Comment: Failing to respond to requests for further information is a poor strategy if you truly want an answer.

Comment: @ElderGeek unlike the other bounty question we discussed last time, where that guy from Tehran, Iran who hadn't signed on in 3 months, this OP had just signed in yesterday.

Comment: you could try running the hud-service command via strace from the terminal to see what its doing. have your tried installing updates ?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Be that as it may, I see no response to Tobias questions. Logging in is not equivalent.

Comment: Find my comments below.

Comment: @kaspa, Would you try creating new user then login using this new account, see if the same happens. (you may try guest login if you have it)

Comment: I lost my launcher after purging compiz as suggested by a comment below

Comment: You should always backup your system prior to making changes to critical OS components. My favorite strategy is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172

Comment: How can I recover my launcher ? I cannot get back compiz.. if I get back I will upgrade to 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

It seems here that the error comes from `compiz` with wrong settings, so I advise you to uninstall and reinstall `compiz`:

```
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
sudo apt-get install compiz* --fix-missing
```

Comment: luchonacho thanks that will makes it easier to read

Comment: `sudo apt-get install compiz* --fix-missing  <br/>
    Reading package lists... Done  <br/>
    Building dependency tree         <br/>
    Reading state information... Done  <br/>
    Note, selecting 'libhtml-template-compiled-perl' for regex 'compiz*'  <br/>
    Note, selecting 'compiz' for regex 'compiz*'  <br/>
    Note, selecting 'c-compiler' for regex 'compiz*'  <br/>
    Note, selecting 'c++-compiler' for regex 'compiz*'`<br/>

Comment: `The following packages were automatically installed and are no     longer required:
  libgles1-mesa libmetacity-private1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libxcb-composite0
  libxcb-xv0 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba xbrlapi
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: That is for second command. The purge command executed successfully .

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because `hud-service` is trying to load, but it's getting a segmentation fault interrupt. You can disable `hud-service` with:

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
```

Then, reboot.

---

You can find more information about HUD-service [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526264/what-is-the-hud-service-responsible-for).

Comment: Hey ! I clicked "Examine locally" when I faced error this time It gave me three options of which I selected "run gdb session". It threw the following.

`There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "apport-retrace" (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

As your comment indicates that you are using Ubuntu 14.10 (which is out of support) my best guess is that you are affected by a bug that was fixed quite some time ago for a currently unsupported version of Ubuntu. I suggest that you update to a currently supported version. Instructions for doing so can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) Another option would be to boot from a [live media](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) of a supported version such as [14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) or [16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)

Comment: Hey sorry !!

I was struggling all these days...

`$ lsb_release -d
Description: Ubuntu 14.10`

Comment: Also note my comment to Benny

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu is 2 years old and is not an LTS release, so it is no longer supported by Canonical or Ask Ubuntu. If you want tech support, please consider upgrading to an up-to-date version that is still supported.

Comment: If I upgrade now does that restore launcher which I lost after giving`sudo apt-get purge compiz*`.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are trying to fix today (October 9, 2016) are coming from (August 2016). To fix the problem you need to find the right error messages first.

Try looking in 'var/log/syslog' for starters.

### Edit 1 - Reinstall Unity

Based on comment below this is the recommended course of action:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I followed one of the suggestion given
`sudo apt-get purge compiz*
sudo apt-get install compiz* --fix-missing`
The first one removed my launcher. Now If I run the second it's throwing error.
I created a new post for it . How to get my launcher back ?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/834869/ubuntu-14-10-launcher-missing

Comment: @kaspa I revised the answer based on the link to your new question which has been put on hold by other users.