# Disable Dash shortcut?

Tags: unity-dash, rhythmbox, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

The Dash keeps popping up, when I use "Alt + right arrow key" to skip to the next track in Rhythmbox. It happens when I skip tracks several times. I'm guessing this is because pressing "Alt" twice starts Dash. Is there any way of changing either shortcut?