# Heroes of Newerth inventory hotkeys

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I'm using 12.04 and when playing **Heroes of Newerth**, I have a problem when trying to use items from my inventory. I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or other combinations but nothing happens.

I figured out that it's because Ubuntu opens that window where you type a command for the application you are currently using. How can I tell Ubuntu not to listen for my `ALT` key when playing HON?

Comment: it's the hud and u can change it using keyboard shortcuts app...but i don't think it will help the game...will it?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @Prasad, it actually worked changing the ALT key to not display the hud in ubuntu.

Comment: @Bogdan If the suggestion solved your issue, could you please write the steps you followed below as an answer and then accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it? Doing so properly marks this question as resolved and better shows other users how to resolve the same problem in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the shortcut for the HUD from <kbd>ALT</kbd> to whatever you like.

- [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)