# Is there a way to ignore Unity ALT menu when using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, unity, shortcut-keys, hud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

I frequently work with Emacs in the GNOME terminal on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a pretty vanilla setup at the moment and I keeping running into this one problem that I haven't been able to resolve.

When using Emacs I frequently use ALT(meta) and probably one out of every ten times I use it my timing is off by just enough that Ubuntu/Unity interprets my ALT as a call for the terminal menu popping up on the HUD. This is frustrating because I am usually typing at such a rapid pace that a ton of my commands get put into the HUD search instead of into the terminal which throws off my work flow. So my question is:

Is there a way to disable the Unity HUD for certain applications or change the way it interprets ALT?

Any approach for solving this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate, I searched several of the key words in my post and the duplicate question did not show up. That being said I have tried changing the 'key to show HUD' to both 'disable' and 'super'. This does not fix the problem and the menu continues to appear when 'alt' is pressed. I noticed that a person who commented on the top answer to the linked question also had this problem. Like I said I have a vanilla set up of 12.04 so I'm not sure what could be causing this. If anyone has any idea please let me know.