# Alt+Tab doesn't work when Citrix is in full screen

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, fullscreen, citrix

I am using 12.04 and in my work we connect to a Citrix XenDesktop. I've installed Citrix Receiver, using [this Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo) and it all works perfectly.

But, I have a problem. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work in full screen mode. There are several adjustments you can choose when logging in, with the **Settings** button in the top right corner.

I like to work with 95% full screen, with the <kbd>windows</kbd> key combination in "full screen mode only". This allows me to use the windows combinations when a work in full screen, inside the remote computer (inside Citrix).

I can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> past the "Citrix computer" when I put it down to 95%. It also allows me to use the "Ubuntu menu" on the left side. But I really can't make this work in Ubuntu.

I've tried to put the windows key combination to "remote server only" and yes, it works inside the server, but also only there and the Ubuntu menu stops working (in example print Screen. I am using this for documentation).

When I try to <kbd>Tab</kbd> from one place to another, even when Citrix isn't in full mode, if I stop there and the continue "tabbing" it continues inside Citrix.

I want to use windows key combination, but only in full screen mode. Does anyone have a solution to fix in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally it's now working. I'm actually accessing remote desktop through web browser Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.

I changed all the setting in Citrix receiver, but didn't realize to change the setting on web page. That is,  after typing username/password for the remote URI in the browser, there is a tab called `setting` (before click **Remote Desktop Connect on AmericasXA...**).

I was able to change the window size to full screen from Seamless. That's it, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and other keys started working fine on the remote desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the file `/etc/icaclient/config/All_Regions.ini`, and set the value `TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote`.

Example `All_Regions.ini` file:

```
...
...
; --- on my system, the setting is on line 601
; These settings control the keyboard settings
;
[Virtual Channels\Keyboard]
TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote
...

...
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/723499/155) was the key to solving the problem on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it, but one likely possibility is that the HUD is grabbing the Alt key.

Please check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key), set the HUD key to another one and check if it helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the tip, but this didn't solve my problem. It seems like Ubuntu don't understand that Citrix is in full window mode.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing i  wrong? I just click on the maximize button, or doubleclick the top of the window to maximize or back to "normal size".

Comment: It seems that Ubuntu understands the Citrix window just "like another maximized screen.

Answer (score 1):

[changing DesiredHRES, DesiredVRES values in All_Regions.ini file worked for me](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX128845)

1. search for file named `All_Regions.ini` in the ica client installation
   dir/config and open it with sudo access (on ubuntu 13.04 the file is
   at this location `/etc/icaclient/config/All_Regions.ini`)
2. Scroll down to the [Virtual Channels\Thinwire Graphics] section.
3. Modify the `DesiredHRES=*` and `DesiredVRES=*` to

   ```
   DesiredHRES=1024
   DesiredVRES=768
   ```
4. Save the file and proceed to launch your XenDesktop session.

Ref: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX128845

Comment: This worked for me (icaclient from Firefox on Ubuntu 13.10), but the setting I changed was `UseFullScreen=false` in the same file. Changing the screen dimensions didn't work for me. Using the ICA client settings panel also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm doing from my system
while you're inside Citrix cloud system

`Ctr + F2` and then `Alt +Tab`

You can access your local system, You can switch back to Citrix cloud System on clicking the Citrix receiver

Answer (score 0):

Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, it always works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing your answer to explain *what* this does.

Comment: ... and it will only work when the it is enabled under 'keyboard shortcuts'

Answer (score -2):

#### Enable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> application toggling in a Citrix XENAPP desktop session

- Open regedit on the client device to edit the registry
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICAClient\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\`
- Open Key: *TransparentKeyPassthrough*
- Set the value to: *Remote*
- Exit the Citrix receiver if it is started and log back into your Citrix desktop.
- When the Citrix desktop session is the active window, you will be able to toggle between the applications in that session with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Erm, the client is an Ubuntu desktop???  There is no registry???

Comment: This answer was the key to solving on my system. The registry key mentioned (TransparentKeyPassthrough) is found in the Linux client config file and can be configured to the same value. See my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/844109/155