# alt tab doesnt work for citrix xenapp in full screen

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, citrix

This question is related, but about 12.04: [Alt+Tab doesn't work when Citrix is in full screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195934/alttab-doesnt-work-when-citrix-is-in-full-screen)

I am using citrix 13.1 xenapp on Kubuntu 14.04, and the suggestions in that post don't work in this configuration.

I am unable to get <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> window switching working. I use an additional monitor docked to my laptop. Hence, I configure the xenapp session window size to the size of the external monitor (1920x1080). I have configured it using settings option in browser (after logging-in).

If I change the layout from 'custom dimensions' to 'fullscreen', <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> works. However, it then occupies all of the screen space, including the laptop's.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to work!

But of course I would like to know how can we know about these shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: click Ctrl+F2, then click alt+Tab.

Comment: nope, doesnt work at my end. I understand by 'ctrl+f2' to make window full-screen. and then use alt+tab normally. However, I have made window full-screen and still, alt-tab doesnt work :(