# Disable Alt (Hold) in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I modify or disable the HUD’s use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

When I hold hold Alt it displays a box in the corner for that programs application menu.  I hate this and its extremly annoying. How do disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

`Keyboard > Shortcuts > launcher`

and just remove the ALT key for showing the HUD.

Comment: system settings > keyboard > shortcuts > launcher  --> http://prntscr.com/2jwyvm