# Alt key in an applications

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, launcher

Unity catches <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressing in various hotkeys combinations which I'm using in the applications, e.g. I'm using remote desktop application with windows on remote host and can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (language switching).

Also local development environments like clion can't be used properly with <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations.

Is there an ability to prevent Unity from catching <kbd>Alt</kbd>? I barely use the launcher - 4 or 5 applications. I really don't need advanced hotkey combinations in Unity itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key

Comment: I think no, that answer is about HUD only. another sample is clion (C++ IDE)  which uses Alt+F7 for some code navigation functionality , how ever Unity overloads this hotkey for own functionality. I'm looking for an ability to switch all Unity hot keys off, there are not required for me at all

Comment: Switch off Alt+F7 hotkey in the keyboard settings.

Comment: Ah, I see, I can remove all hot keys there, thank you