# (14.04) How to disable ALT (Hold) - "Reveals application menu"?

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, hud

I looked at [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key) and the accepted solution doesn't work for me.

The second-best solution uses ccsm which seems to be recommended against. I also tried https://askubuntu.com/a/337210/438411 which didn't work for me.

To clarify, I'm trying to remove the behavior where the application menu activates when holding ALT within an application. It's very annoying if I'm in terminal and using emacs (-nw), or firefox + firemacs

What's the best way to do remove this functionality? It's really frustrating :(