# Select ONLY the address bar in Chrome using Alt + D on Linux?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

It's quite easy on Windows to go to the Google Chrome's address bar using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Whenever, I was trying to use the same on Ubuntu Linux, not only the address bar is getting selected but also **the command acceptor**:

[image: Alt + D on Ubuntu]

How do you select ONLY the address bar in Chrome on Linux?

Comment: Control+L like any other browser doesn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options:

- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select only the address bar
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> like in any other browser

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> should also work if you *hold down* <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then hit <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: It would be cool, if could I could give you +2. This works with just **single** button.

Comment: @Pilot6 We have to wait for few minutes. THE SYSTEM

Comment: Could you address OP's point about the "command acceptor"? Is that the HUD which, IIRC, is invoked by pressing the (left?) *alt* key? (I use Lubuntu which doesn't have Unity's HUD.)

Comment: @DK Bose. You're right. It's the HUD.

Comment: And to change the shortcut key see https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key

Answer (score 1):

I went to setting and found that ALT+D was assigned to another function (KDE activiteies). I changed this to another shortcut and now It works.