# Preventing HUD on Windows key (not Alt)

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I took a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key) but it didn't seem quite to help: my issue is not that <kbd>Alt</kbd> causes the HUD to pop up, but rather the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key right next to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> causes it to pop up. My finger slips off the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key maybe ten times a day, and then my Ubuntu VM very very slowly starts loading the HUD, and then steals whatever text I had just typed and then stalls for a few seconds, and then I can hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> again and then it very very slowly fades the HUD back out. It completely ruins my workflow.

I haven't yet been able to figure out how to override the setting - in the above-reference question, it recommends resetting the HUD to some other combination; but *even at this screen*, hitting the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key pops up the HUD, so I cannot figure out how to rename/reassign/delete this "feature".

Comment: @the-brown-one thanks for the formatting help - I couldn't remember how to get keyboard keys (thought I tried `<kbd>` but I guess not. Also, I wasn't positive that `Windows` key was same as <kbd>Super</kbd>, so I didn't want to confuse the issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: I just don't like Windows, so I prefer the Linux appropriate term :P

Comment: Oh, me too! It just... has a Windows logo on it, and in ignorance of better alternatives.