# Disable alt+e, alt+f, etc shortcuts

Tags: unity, keyboard, wine, shortcut-keys

I am using 14.04.
I tried steps covered here: [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)
Tapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> have no effect, but still <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> opens Edit menu from navigation bar, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> opens File menu etc.
I would like to disable these shortcuts, because it causes full screen Wine applications to freeze.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello from 2021. This is still impossible in Unity7. So, let's wait another five years. May be they'll fix that...