# How to Disable Hovering-App-Bar in 16.04?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, touchpad, usability

I get this hovering bar as an artifact popping many times per hour without pressing Alt-Tab, which duration 3-15 seconds with/without interaction of mouse/touchpad/keyboard

- booting other Ubuntus and Linuxes other than 16.04 does not lead to the same problem etc with USB boots so it is a software problem in 16.04, not hardware problem (this laptop has been 3x in Support and has regular checkups)

[image]

- Artifact activates sometimes just by touches with touchpad
- [Sneetsher's](https://askubuntu.com/a/787823/25388) one-liners do not resolve the case

  ```
  # disable Alt-tab keybinding
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward "'Disabled'"
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-prev "'Disabled'"
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward-all "'Disabled'"
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward "'Disabled'"
  # prevent it, since complete disable not possible
  dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins "$(dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins | sed "s/]/, 'staticswitcher']/")"
  ```
- [JonasCz's](https://askubuntu.com/a/783822/25388) answer. His proposal is the same as Sneetsher's first set of one-liners. In other words, the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package does not disable the hovering bar. It only disables ALT-Tab key. I still get the artifact from the touchpad only.
- Default settings. I have default Compiz settings. No hot-corners etc.

[image]

I really would like to have one liner about disabling the feature because it helps me much in many systems and future upgrades/updates.

Troubleshooting methods active

- JonasCz. Keeping now `xev` on and trying to found which inputs causes the artifact.

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4 and 4.6
Linux kernel options: wl
Keyboard layout: Dvorak-US = English (Dvorak)
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid (6.2)

Comment: "
    I have noticed that the artifact activates sometimes just by touches with touchpad
" also  check if you set it as one of the "hot corners" in "compiz"

Comment: @Rinzwind I have default settings in all aspects. I have no hot corners or others in my system active.

Comment: Another idea regarding troubleshooting: try running `xev` in a terminal, which will tell you exactly what input events there are. Then you could narrow down what is causing this, maybe the touchpad is doing things on it's own ?

Comment: @Masi Does it happen in the Guest session?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Alt + Tab switcher in Compiz Settings manager. To do so:

- Install the Compiz Settings manager with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Find "CompizConfig Settings manager" in the dash, open it, find the Ubuntu Unity plugin, go to the "Switcher" tab, and disable all shortcuts and checkboxes.

This will disable the Alt + tab application switcher popup.

Comment: This solution solves the case with using ALT-Tab key but I still get the artifact. This method does not disable the function. I receive now once again those artifacts about after 5 minutes of use the compiz thing.

Comment: @Masi, In that case, I have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is some thing you may try:

1. Same as JonasCz, disable shortcuts of switcher by `ccsm` → Desktop section → Ubuntu Unity Plugin → Switcher tab or using commands:

   ```
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward "'Disabled'"
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-prev "'Disabled'"
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward-all "'Disabled'"
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/alt-tab-forward "'Disabled'"
   ```

   Still one shortcut I wasn't able to find <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, seem hard-coded that why they flag [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85110/disable-alt-shortcut) as duplicate of [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)
2. As there is no way to disable default unity switcher, try overriding it by another. Do in Window Management section → Enable *Application Switcher* or *Static Application Switcher* or using command:

   ```
   dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins "$(dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins | sed "s/]/, 'staticswitcher']/")"
   ```

Comment: Can you give one-liners for your 2nd proposal?

Comment: @Masi, as requested.

Comment: I tested your second option. I still get the hovering bar artifact. It both of those are not enough. Do you know what can help next?

Answer (score 0):

In Unity tweak tool (that can be installed by `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` or `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool` in 16.04) go to <kbd>Switcher</kbd>, disable everything and see if it works. If neither of the answers work, chances are your touchpad and keyboard share inputs and the touchpad has gone crazy.

EDIT: If nothing happens, boot into another OS and see if a similar switcher pops up by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and again by using the touchpad. If this keeps happening, then it's a hardware problem.

Comment: I'm not sure whether 'dconf-editor' is in the official repositories, but have you tried if it helps? I'm not sure, I'm typing this from a phone.

Comment: I'm clueless. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> launches an almost ubiquitous command. Does it happen elsewhere out of Ubuntu?

Comment: @aaltnate I am confused what you mean? I get the artifact also by just touching the touchpad. I disabled ALT+Tab already but I still the artifact.

Comment: So, did you try it? On another Ubuntu live USB, on OSX or on another OS?

Comment: Of course. I still get the artifact. See the body. I do not think this is a hardware problem, this is a software problem!

Comment: @Masi If it also happens outside of Ubuntu then it's certainly not a problem with the Ubuntu system/partition (software problem). If you dual boot or boot off of an USB stick there's no way for the partitions to share data during boot, as long as they don't mount on boot (by default, they don't). The only variable that stays the same is the hardware, and the result is still the same (the switcher pops up even with no interaction). So there HAS to be something wrong with it.

Comment: Please, read the body. It does not happen outside Ubuntu. I do not have dual boot or boot off of an USB stick. This is a software issue.

Comment: @Masi and I asked you to try booting off one. Burn an image somewhere and boot from it. See if you still get the switcher to open up. If it does, it's a hardware problem, if it doesn't, it's a software problem. And I don't know of any action to take if none of the common tools works.

Comment: Of course, I have booted many USB images in the laptop. There is no switcher there. Just in 16.04 Ubuntu. It is a software problem.