# How do I disable the ALT hotkey in Unity?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, games

I'd like to use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key for my games, but every time I press it it minimizes my game and brings up a window that I'll never use.

How do I disable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open **System settings > Keyboard settings > Shortcuts** tab.
- Select *Key to show the HUD* and press <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>.

In this way you can disable the ALT hotkey in unity.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.  Its much simpler than I thought it would be - I was expecting to have to use the terminal and install some packages and stuff.