# disabling alt-key from asking "Type your command"

Tags: unity, launcher, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, with the new unity theme.

Every time I click on the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, it goes to "Type your command". However, I am using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change layouts, and if I don't time releasing the shift correctly, it jumps into typing a command, which is annoying.

Anything I can do to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd> as a "Type your command" option?
Thanks

Comment: You can try using shift+alt (i.e. shift before alt) to change the keyboard layout instead ;-)

Comment: I wanted to keep my habits from windows. Eventually I left to the new Ubuntu layout, instead of unity, and it got my problems solved

Comment: Solved here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key