# gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud doesn't work on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, hud

I want to disable showing HUD and application menus via left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I've seen on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/518384/23006) that you were able to do that in 14.04 but now (with 18.04) it doesn't work:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.integrated show-hud "['']"
No such schema “org.compiz.integrated”
```

The option `Key to show the HUD` doesn't exist in keyboard settings anymore as stated in [another askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/122232/23006).

I'm using the Gnome Shell as DE.

For example when using Visual Studio Code I have menu bar being shown every time I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> even though I have disabled it or changed the key combination for this.

[image: visual studio code menu bar]

How can I achieve this then?

Comment: GNOME 3 doesn't even has HUD in the first place, how is it showing up? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @pomsky I was referring here to the in app menus. Changed the question (attached a screenshot)