# Prevent Alt from triggering global menu

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, input-language

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Two times out of three when I'm trying to switch a language using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> the window's global menu opens instead.

I don't ever use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to access the window's global menu, and I need to have the language switched consistently, and without Ubuntu losing the focus of the field I'm typing in. As such, completely disabling the functionality of opening the window global menu with <kbd>Alt</kbd> seems like a good solution.

I have read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455519/how-to-stop-alt-from-triggering-global-menu) thread and none of the solutions provided there have worked. Specifically:

- CompizConfig Settings Manager doesn't list anything resembling Ubuntu Unity Plugin, or "Key to show the menu bar while pressed", or anything similar either in Desktop or anywhere else.
- There's no way to disable the Key to show the HUD as, apparently, GNOME v3 doesn't have HUD at all (as evidenced in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192708/gsettings-set-org-compiz-integrated-show-hud-doesnt-work-on-18-04#comment1996448_1192708) thread).
- The Keyboard Shortcuts menu also doesn't seem to contain any shortcuts for just the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. There was a shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for action "Activate the window menu", I have disabled it. Still, simply pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key opens the window global menu (for example, in a browser).

Perhaps, somebody has any up-to-date suggestions for preventing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key from opening the global menu and shifting focus from the field I'm currently typing in?

P.S. I know that I can use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but it is very inconvenient for me.

UPD: I'm talking about the window main menu, like [this](https://ibb.co/g9Sz72d). Each app has a different one, some apps don't explode the list but just focusing the window main menu [like Skype](https://ibb.co/0nnBkxV). It doesn't matter, the problem is that clicking Alt focuses on this main menu in the first place, even when used in a shortcut. I want to disable this behavior.

Comment: What is "windows global menu"? Please describe more specifically what you mean by this.

Comment: Any fixes? Have the same problem